# Making gridcell take on value of largest region within gridcell with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, fields-attributes

I am new to QGIS and very excited about all its features. We want to match gridcells to a region, when a gridcell lies in more than one region we want to assign the largest region to the gridcell.

Up till now we have been working with "connect with attributes on basis of place" to assign the region name to the gridcell. We are not familiar with R or Python.

Is there anyway we can do this without using these programs?

Comment: which version of QGIS are u using ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the DB Manager of QGIS.

You choose **Database / Database Manager / Database Manager** then **Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers**

You can then try the following query :

```
select grid.id,max(st_area(intersection(reg.geometry,grid.geometry))),reg.name
from grid, region_layer reg
where st_intersects(grid.geometry, reg.geometry)
group by grid.id
```

***grid_layer*** being your grid layer and **reg_layer** being your region layer...

This query generates the id of the cell followed by the surface of intersection and the region's name.

You can then load the result in the layer manager. You can also join this resulting layer to your grid layer if you want to insert the region's name in your initial table.

***PS*** : adapt the query according to your data structure ...

---

According to your data structure the query should look like this :

```
select prio_gid.gid,
max(st_area(intersection(GADM36_KEN_1.geometry,prio_gid.geometry))),GADM36_KEN_1.NAME_1
from prio_gid, GADM36_KEN_1
where st_intersects(prio_gid.geometry,GADM36_KEN_1.geometry)
group by prio_gid.gid
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. We are struggeling to adapt the query to our data structure. Would you be able to help us? We have a layer with gridcells called "prio_gid", within that layer the gridcell number is in the colom "gid" of our attribute table. Our region layer is called "GADM36_KEN_1" and within that layer the name of the region is in the colom "NAME_1" of our attribute table.

Comment: just to make sure I have asked my question clearly, some more explination on what we want to do. We want to match regions to our gridcells. The regions are larger than the gridcells and eventually we want all gridcells to be assigned a region. When a gridcell is in two regions we want  the gridcell to get the name of the largest region.

Comment: we have now written the code 'select gid.id, max(st_area(intersection(NAME_1.geometry,gid.geometry))),NAME_1.name
from priogrid_cell, gadm36_KEN_1 reg
where st_intersects(gid.geometry, NAME_1.geometry)
group by gid.id'

Comment: And get this error term: Query execution error on DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ""; CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "" USING QgsVLayer('virtual','',UTF-8): 1 - Provider error:

virtual: Malformed URL

Comment: i edited my answer !

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. We  stell get the following error term, would you know what to do with this? Query execution error on DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ""; CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "" USING QgsVLayer('virtual','',UTF-8): 1 - Provider error:

virtual: Malformed URL

Comment: We first tried using this track Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers. But we do not have the option Qgis Layers. We then came to virtual layers by clicking: Maplayers / add layer / add virtual layer then we type the query in the query box.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's not (or not any longer ...) Qgis Layers but **Project layers** ... do u see it ? ... i think both scenario should be working but can u retry in **Virtual layers/Project layers** ?

Comment: Ah yeah we found it, thank you once again! Its been running for a couple of hours now, we are wondering if we should adjust our grid file, as we have used a prio.grid map of the whole world while we are only linking it to regions in 22 countries in Africa. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not that good on that topic, i think u should refine your choice of projection to choose the closest to your area of interest ... did u succeed in running the query ? do the results make sense ?

Comment: He did accept the query, but he is still running it. So we were wondering if it is taking so long as the query is also attempting to match the many gridcells in the world that are not connected to any of our regions in Africa

Comment: So we wonder if with this query also includes those gridcells without overlap with our regions

Comment: No that's sure ... the query handles **intersection cases only** ... is the query still running ? how big is your dataset ? if you cover all the continent with tiny cells of 5 meters there are some chances your computer explodes ...

Comment: we led it run for three hours and then gave up, but were gonna give it another go. our grids are 55 km x 55 km. Do you think that should be a problem?

Comment: Most important is the number of features in every layer ... how many regions and how many cells do u have ?